# How to display another form with datagridview just below a textbox to filter grid data

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have created a usercontrol. It has two textbox one for description and another for id.

Next I have created a form with datagridview. Datasource for this datagridview is sent from predefined usercontrol. It will have only two colums ID and Description.

Now I want when text on usercontrol textbox for description is changed, form with datagridview displays just below textbox and displays matching data as reference. Form should keep on displaying till user press enter or leaves the textbox. While displaying form user should be able to type text on usercontrol textbox for filter.

And when user leaves the textbox or presses enter, value from selected row of datagridview id column and descriptions column should be passed to usercontrol.

I did everything well but when form with datagridview appears, displayed form becomes active and I can not continue writing in searching textbox of usercontrol.

Comment: does it have to be a form ? Why not create a panel containing the DataGridView and set the parent of the panel to the form where the textbox is on. That way you dont have to worry about loosing focus, and the user wont be able anymore to drag the form somewhere else

Comment: Great, It is a good idea. I had tried it with changing height of the form, but it is disappeared by other overlapping panel. As i see, if panel is used instead of form, i need to  create panel in every form where i wish to use this idea. I want it to be used as combobox for which we just sent datasource, and use as component  whereever needed. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try showing the form inactive with the following extension method:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    #region Show inactive top-most

    const int  SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE =  4,
                HWND_TOPMOST      = -1;
    const uint SWP_NOACTIVATE    = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(int  hWnd,            // window handle
                                    int  hWndInsertAfter, // placement-order handle
                                    int  X,               // horizontal position
                                    int  Y,               // vertical position
                                    int  cx,              // width
                                    int  cy,              // height
                                    uint uFlags);         // window positioning flags

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    public static void ShowInactiveTopMost(this Form form)
    {
        ShowWindow(form.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);

        SetWindowPos(form.Handle.ToInt32(),
                        HWND_TOPMOST,
                        form.Left,
                        form.Top,
                        form.Width,
                        form.Height,
                        SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }

    #endregion
}
```